# How would I find the area of a function over a specific interval?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

How would I find the area of a function over a specific interval?

For example: $g(x) = e^{5x}$

Find the area of the function over the interval $[-4, 2]$.

Comment: What does "find the area of the function" mean? Do you mean find the area between the graph of `g` and the `x`-axis? In which case, `Integrate[g[x], {x, -4, 2}]`. But on the face of it, this doesn't seem like a question about the computing software *Mathematica*.

Comment: Use Integration on function and then apply limits.

Comment: Welcome to _Mathematica_.SE. Are you sure you are posting on the right site? There is nothing in your question making it clear that it is concerned with _Mathematica_ software.

Comment: The question is not clear, I am fairly certain that it means between the curve and the x-axis. I tried to input Integrate[g[x], {x, -4, 2}], however, I got the output of (-1+e^30)/(5e^20) which doesn't seem to be the correct answer

Comment: @NickS. Looks right to me http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+e%5e(5x)+from+-4+to+2

Comment: That maybe the correct answer for the particular problem, however, when I try Integrate[f[x], {x, 1, 5}] I get the output of ((1/5)e^5)(-1+e^20) which I know is incorrect. The answer should come out to be 76/3.

Answer (score 3):

I think you mean you want to calculate the area between a function and the x-axis.

Define the function :

```
g[x_] := E^(5 x)
```

Show the area between the function and x-axis over the interval `[−4,2]` :

```
Plot[g[x], {x, -4, 2}, PlotRange -> Full, Filling -> Axis, FillingStyle -> Yellow]
```

[image]

With the knowledge of Calculus, the area can be computed with the following expression:

```
area = Integrate[g[x], {x, -4, 2}]
```

And the result is: $$\frac{e^{30}-1}{5 e^{20}}$$

Numeric result:

```
 N@Integrate[g[x], {x, 1, 5}]
```

> ```
> 1.4401*10^10
> ```

---

> The question is not clear, I am fairly certain that it means between the curve and the x-axis. I tried to input Integrate[g[x], {x, -4, 2}], however, I got the output of (-1+e^30)/(5e^20) which doesn't seem to be the correct answer – @Nick S.
>
> That maybe the correct answer for the particular problem, however, when I try Integrate[f[x], {x, 1, 5}] I get the output of ((1/5)e^5)(-1+e^20) which I know is incorrect. The answer should come out to be 76/3. – @Nick S.

However, from the plot of the function, the area do be a large number. Maybe either your *standard answer* or the expression of question is incorrect.

Comment: That should be `E` instead of `e`, no?

Comment: @J.M. I will correct the answer.